# how can I consume django web service in C#?

Tags: c#, python, django, serialization, simplejson

python - django webmethod returns simplejson.dumps,
how can I convert the simplejson string into C# 2.0 Object ?

for example,
dict -> Hashtable
string -> String
...

is there any **JSON Serializable** library in existing .NET framework or any 3rd party tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the JSON.net project hosted at GitHub : [JSON.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)

Comment: although json.net is good alternative but I end up with XMLRPC instead JSON, and used http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/XML-RPC, as using CookComputing.net its much easy !

Comment: Also www.xml-rpc.net is easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Tried [System.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json%28VS.95%29.aspx)?